# How can I troubleshoot a query timeout issue in a BackgroundService that utilizes DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a query timeout issue with DocumentMoveData.TemplateFiles method that I can't resolve. The method is called by three BackgroundServices derived from the same base class. The only difference between the services is the query parameter. The services use IServiceScopeFactory to create a scope, get IDocumentMoveData from the scope, and call TemplateFiles method. The method uses DBContext to execute a LINQ query against SQL Server. The same query executed in SQL Management Console takes less than 1 second.

What steps should I take to resolve this issue?

```
public class DocumentMoveService : BackgroundService {
    private IServiceScopeFactory _services;
public DocumentMoveService(IServiceScopeFactory services) {
_services = services;
}
}
public class DocumentMoveServiceOne : DocumentMoveService{}
public class DocumentMoveServiceTwo : DocumentMoveService{}

I omit other parameters in DocumentMoveService for brevity, none of the parameters are using DBContext.

DocumentMoveService has ExecuteAsync that is used by all three classes, only the query parameter is different.


protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           try
            {
                using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    docV1Factory = scopedServices.GetService<IDocumentMoveData>();
        – the following call uses DBContext see DocumentMoveData constructor below
                    filesToProcess = await docV1Factory.TemplateFiles(10, _storageConfig.FileType);
        foreach (DocumentInfo f in filesToProcess)
                    {
            …
                                await docV1Factory.Save(f, destfile, (int)_storageConfig.FileType);
                    }

// 
public interface IDocumentMoveData
    {
        Task Save(DocumentInfo docinfo, IStorageFile savedfile, int ftype);
        Task<List<DocumentInfo>> TemplateFiles(int count, eFormsModel.DataObjects.DocumentFile.TypeEnum ftype);
    }
    
public class DocumentMoveData : IDocumentMoveData    {
        private readonly DBContext _context;

        public DocumentMoveData(DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

 public async Task Save(DocumentInfo docinfo, IStorageFile savedfile, int ftypeid)
        {

            int storageid = await GetStorageId(savedfile.Folder);
            DocTemplateFile newret = new DocTemplateFile()... // init code removed for brevity
            _context.DocumentTemplateFiles.Add(newret);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

public async Task<List<DocumentInfo>> TemplateFiles(int count, eFormsModel.DataObjects.DocumentFile.TypeEnum ftype)
        {
            try
            {
                var query =  _context.DocumentFiles
                    .Include(o=> o.Document)
                    .Where(df => df.FileTypesId == Convert.ToInt32(ftype))
                    .Where(c => !_context.DocumentTemplateFiles.Any(cc => cc.OriginalDocId == c.DocumentsId))
                    .Select(df => new DocumentInfo
                    {
                        DocumentFileId = df.Id,
                        FileName = df.FileName,
                        DocumentId = df.DocumentsId,
                        UserId = _context.Documents
                            .Where(d => d.Id == df.DocumentsId)
                            .Select(d => d.UploadedByUserId)
                            .FirstOrDefault(),
                        CustomerId = _context.Users
                            .Where(u => u.LoginId == _context.Documents
                                .Where(d => d.Id == df.DocumentsId)
                                .Select(d => d.UploadedByUserId)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
                            .Select(u => u.CustomersId)
                            .FirstOrDefault(),
                        WhenCreated = df.Document.UploadedDate
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(df => df.DocumentId)
                    .Take(count);
                List<DocumentInfo> documentFileInfos = query.ToList();
                return documentFileInfos;
            }
}

Initialization in Program.cs
hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
    {
        var t = config.GetConnectionString("connstr");
        options.UseSqlServer(t);
    }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

    services.AddScoped<DBContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentMoveData, DocumentMoveData>();

        services.AddHostedService<DocumentMoveService>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DocumentMoveService>>();
            var scopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            StorageTypeByTaskType[configFType.FileType] = typeof(DocumentMoveService);
            return new DocumentMoveService(logger, scopeFactory, configFType);

// same for two additional backgroundservices
        services.AddHostedService<DocumentMoveServiceOne>(serviceProvider =>
        services.AddHostedService<DocumentMoveServiceTwo>(serviceProvider =>
          ..
        });
```

With this call:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => { var t = config.GetConnectionString("connstr"); options.UseSqlServer(t); });
```

the query degradation happens after about 100 iteration. With this call:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => { var t = config.GetConnectionString("connstr"); options.UseSqlServer(t); }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

it happens immediately

Generated query:

```
declare  @__p_1 int, @__ToInt32_0 int
select @__p_1 = 10, @__ToInt32_0 = 2
SELECT [t].[ID] AS [DocumentFileId], [t].[FileName], [t].[Documents_ID] AS [DocumentId], COALESCE((
    SELECT TOP(1) [d2].[UploadedBy_User_ID]
    FROM [Documents] AS [d2]
    WHERE [d2].[ID] = [t].[Documents_ID]), 0) AS [UserId], COALESCE((
    SELECT TOP(1) [u].[Customers_ID]
    FROM [Users] AS [u]
    WHERE [u].[login_id] = COALESCE((
        SELECT TOP(1) [d3].[UploadedBy_User_ID]
        FROM [Documents] AS [d3]
        WHERE [d3].[ID] = [t].[Documents_ID]), 0)), 0) AS [CustomerId], [d1].[UploadedDate] AS [WhenCreated]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_1) [d].[ID], [d].[Documents_ID], [d].[FileName]
    FROM [DocumentFiles] AS [d]
    WHERE [d].[FileTypes_ID] = @__ToInt32_0 AND NOT (EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [DocumentTemplateFiles] AS [d0]
        WHERE [d0].[OriginalDocId] = [d].[Documents_ID]))
    ORDER BY [d].[Documents_ID] DESC
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Documents] AS [d1] ON [t].[Documents_ID] = [d1].[ID]
ORDER BY [t].[Documents_ID] DESC
```

Documents :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
...*(other fields)*
CONSTRAINT [PK_Documents] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

DocumentFiles:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentFiles](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Documents_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FileTypes_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
*.. (other fields)*
CONSTRAINT [PK_Files] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? you probably want to have a look at the generated queries, and the query plans for them. Please [edit] your post and show that, as well as relevant tables and index definitions.

Comment: Thank you! I added generated query to the end in the body of the question. I'll publish table definitions. Do you think that query itself is an issue since it executes just fine in sql management studio (under 1 second)?

Comment: It doesn't look great I must say. If the tables are well indexed it might not be too bad, but some of those joins/subqueries look like they should have been navigation properties, which might have generated a better query. Narrowing the amount of columns you are retrieving might also help.

Comment: I added this to the body of the question. With this call:
 services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
    {
        var t = config.GetConnectionString("connstr");
        options.UseSqlServer(t);
    });

the query degradation happens after about 100 iteration.

With this call:

services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
    {
        var t = config.GetConnectionString("connstr");
        options.UseSqlServer(t);
    }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
it happens immediately

Comment: Please also share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Shared query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJggxZ2X3

Comment: You have an async function, but block a thread with this call `List<DocumentInfo> documentFileInfos = query.ToList();`. It is much better to use `ToListAsync`

Comment: Next you calling `SaveChangesAsync` for each `DocumentInfo` object, you can do this once after the the loop. And since you create objects, you can probably consider `BulkInsertAsync` extenstion

Comment: E.Shcherbo - thank you! Will try now and let everyone :) know how it went.

Comment: Following is the execution log. As you can see the code does not even reach "SaveChangesAsync":
main thread starting. Build version 4.30.0.0
DocumentMoveService constructor
DocumentMoveServiceOne constructor
DocumentMoveServiceTwo constructor
0,FileType:  converteddocs From:source1 To: source2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandError,"Failed executing DbCommand (30,197ms) [Parameters=[@__p_1='?' (DbType = Int32), @__ToInt32_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']